# How Client can know that Server has terminated the SSL Connection

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

When I am calling `SSL_write()` from client's end and if Server has already terminated the SSL Connection, First `SSL_Write()` is successful (returns correct number of bytes). However as soon as I perform second `SSL_Write()`, Client Process/Application terminates unexpectedly. Is there anyway to find out that Server has closed the SSL connection and Client should not perform any further Writes? To close SSL Connection on Server side, I am calling following syscalls:

`close(server_fd);`

`SSL_CTX_free(ctx);`

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `SSL_write`? From the documentation, it should return 0 if the connection was terminated

Comment: SSL_Write never returns 0.

Comment: Odd, it crashes for you before `SSL_write` returns at all? It should return 0, or at least some negative value indicating an error if it wasnt successful in sending out data (which if your server closed the connection, it shouldnt be successful)

Comment: `SSL_write()` should not be terminating the program on failure. That means something else is going on, memory is likely getting corrupted somewhere, and `SSL_write()` is the unwitting victim of it